# After Cherry Pick in Azure DevOps, source branch still showing merged changes

Tags: azure-devops, cherry-pick

We have dev, release, and master branches. On the Dev branch, we have 10 Pull requests and I want to merge only 5 pull requests from Dev to the release branch, so I used cherry-pick option and merged 5 pull requests into the release branch. and that looks good.

After a week I tried to merge all the remaining 5 PR from the development branch to the release branch. but it is showing a total 10 PR that needs to be merged into the release branch. but 5 out of 10 were merged into the release branch using a cherry pick.

Why it's showing 10 PR in the dev branch even after merging 5 PR into the release branch using cherry pick? I was expecting only the remaining 5 PR should show.

Thanks

After merging changes with Cherry Pick it should not show changes in the source branch.  source branch should show only pending changes which need to be merged to another branch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We have Branch-1 and branch-2, branch-1 has 10 commits, and I merged 5 commits from branch-1 to branch-2 using cherry pick. 
After a week, I tried to merge the remaining 5 commits from branch-1 to branch-2, but it’s showing 10 commit differences between branch-1 and branch-2, I already merged 5 commits using a cherry-pick, why it’s showing again 10 commits differences?